# How to turn off range value display on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, range

I'm styling a custom range element. I've gotten down to trying to normalize it in IE (works in the other browsers I care about).

Separate from the other browsers, IE seems to display a small box with the value while you're moving the thumb around.

I can't seem to figure out how to get this value display to go away, I have my own value display coded separately and would like to use that consistently.

Does anyone know what controls that value element and how to hide it?

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for the [`::-ms-tooltip` pseudo-element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465805.aspx):

```css
::-ms-tooltip { display: none; }
```

[image]